# Перебор аффинных функций из 4 переменных и нахождение веса Хэмминга

Tags: python

Дана булева функция f вида x1x2+x3x4. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с кодом перебора аффинных функций для 4 переменных , не знаю как вывести построение таблиц истинности и найти вес хэмминга между f вида x1x2+x3x4 и аффинными функциями для 4 переменных.
https://pastebin.com/9qnvTMu2